# How to create a javascript/jquery real time check for banned words in an input field

Tags: jquery, real-time

I've searched high and low, but just can't find a suitable solution for this issue.... we have an input field in which we don't want people to put certain words.  Words such as "unit" or "level" or "apartment" etc...

What we need is a js based real time banned word check that can show a specific error message if we detect the user has typed one of the banned words.

Must be real time so we catch it before they attempt to submit the form.

There are lots of posts on various aspects of this question, but none that seem to match all the elements.

A simple js fiddle example would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put them in an array....loop through array...check if each word exists in input value...remove if applicable using string methods. Start with a string and an array and get that working...then focus on doing it with the value of an input. Come back when you have some actual code that isn't working as expected

Comment: Stack overflow isn't here to do your work for you. Post examples of code you've tried.

Comment: apologies for spoon-feeding him. it's just that i already have the code from the past asker, i just modified it a bit for him. wont do it again.

Comment: Oh please. Don't apologise for helping a brother out Kapitan. Not everyone's as clever as you, Jacin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

i have not created a jsfidlle, all you need to do is copy-paste this on a text file then save it with a .html extension.

```
<script>
function checkBanWords()
{
  var banned_words = ['apple', 'berry', 'citrus'];
  var textvalue = document.getElementById('name').value;
  for(var i=0; i<banned_words.length; i++) {
    if (~textvalue.indexOf(banned_words[i])){

      //DO YOUR STUFF HERE

      console.log('you have entered a banned word: ' + banned_words[i]);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="checkBanWords()" />
```

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was trying to do.